# Checking for navigator.globalization on deviceready returns undefined on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 2.2.0 on iOS and binding to the devicready event to see if the navigator.globalization object is there. I am getting undefined.

My code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    alert('deviceready');
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(function(d)
    {
        window.localStorage.setItem('localeLanguage', d.value);
        console.log('localeLanguage: is'+d.value);
    },
    function(error)
    {
        console.log('error getting locale language');
    });
}
```

The `alert('deviceready')` never fires. I am really at a loss here. I'm setting up my scripts as follows.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //alert(typeof navigator.globalization);
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.map.services.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.i18n.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/languages.js"></script>
<script src="js/oakglobalization.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Any ideas would be helpful as this is a showstopper now.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Do you fixed this issue? Pleas post answers

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
});
```

to add you event listener.

And maybe try to update your cordova version. The current version is the 2.6.0.

Another point : with phonegap, use the Navigator.notification.alert method instead of the native javascript alert. More info [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert).

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved it or not, but at least for me ( PG 3.3.0 ) using navigator.globalization I had to install the cordova plugin and change the XML accordingly.

```
command-line> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.globalization
config.xml>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    </feature>
```

On that note, it didn't work on browser emulators ( ie.: ripple ) only on the real iOS xcode emulator ...
Backup your project just in case ;)